# How to specify arguments in map in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming

Can I specify other arguments in map ?

For example, I have the following code:

```
def f(a, b):
    return a + b
l = [1, 2, 3]
ll = map(f, l)
```

How can I give an argument to the `map` above so that each element of `ll` is the sum of one element in `l` and the given argument?

For example, if I can use something like `map(f(2,), l)`, I will get `[3, 4, 5]` as result.

I know I can achieve the same result by list comprehension, or a for loop, but I just want to know if it is possible to do it in a `map` way.

Comment: if you don't want to store the result you could just convert the list comprehension into a for loop

Comment: Are you looking for `reduce` instead of `map`? What is the expected output of this code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`map` itself does not directly provide a way to do that.  However, you can do it by using `functools.partial` to pre-specify the static argument:

```
>>> def add(x, y):
...     return x+y
>>> map(functools.partial(add, y=10), [1, 2, 3])
[11, 12, 13]
```

However, as @jamylak suggested in a comment, there's little reason to do this.  If you don't want to store the result, just do a regular for loop:

```
for item in [1, 2, 3]:
   add(item, 10)
```

Comment: What if I replace partial with lambda x:add(x, 10)? What's the difference? Both in performance and results. Thanks!

Comment: @SpiritZhang: There's no difference in results.  I imagine there's not much difference performance-wise either, but you can test that for yourself if you want.  There's not much point in worrying about the performance of different ways of doing it with `map` when there's no reason to do it with `map` in the first place.

Comment: @SpiritZhang, `map(lambda x: add(x, 10), [1, 2, 3])` gives `NameError: global name 'add' is not defined`.  One can say `map(lambda x: x.__add__(10), [1, 2, 3])` but if you bother with a lambda you might as well say `map(lambda x: x+10, [1, 2, 3])`

Comment: @jwpat7: I defined the `add` function in my example.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for [`functools.partial`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), which is used to implement [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application):

```
ll = map(functools.partial(f, 2), l)
```

Note that in many cases, a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) or [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) is more readable:

```
ll = [f(2, x) for x in l]
```

Comment: nice, but partial application != currying.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `map()` for this but a list comprehension:

```
new_lst = [f(x, other_value) for x in lst]
```

Another option would be a lambda. But don't do that:

```
new_lst = map(lambda x: map(x, other_value), lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider :-

```
def f(a):
    return a + b
l = [1, 2, 3]
b = 2
ll = map(f,l)

print ll
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you want:

```
  listA=[1,2,3]

  def f(a,b=2):
    return a+b

  result = map(f,listA)

  print result
```

or if you have the same number of items in two lists, you can do:

```
  listA=[1,2,3]
  listB=[2,2,2]
  def f(a,b):
    return a+b

  result = map(f,listA,listB)

  print result
```